# redirect back to previous page after login keeping entered form information

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I return to the previous page after the user has logged in using asp .net c# razor?  The previous page is a long multi-page form that the user has already entered a lot of data, so I don't want the user to lose that information.  Using return Redirect(returnUrl) goes back to the page, but all of the data that was in the ViewBag from the previous form pages is lost.

Comment: `user has already entered a lot of data` if these data stored in database then you can query it and set to the ViewBag

Comment: If it is not saved then you can temporarily store it into the browser `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` and get it back when you need it

Comment: Data entered on a form is never posted back to the `Viewbag`.  Your question makes no sense from that point of view.

Comment: this makes no sense dude

Comment: Sorry for the confusion with my question.  Here's the scenario -

Comment: Sorry for the confusion with my question.  Here's the scenario - The user is typing information on a form that is multiple pages.  The last page of the form checks to see if the user is logged in before submitting it.  If the user isn't logged in, they would click on the login button.  This takes them to the login screen.  After successful login I want the user to go back to where they were when completing the form.  The data entered in the form hasn't been saved in the database as of yet.  When I redirect the user back to the previous page the data they entered on the screen is lost